# Wordpress: Top menu not showing in 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, menu

I have a problem trying to add the top-menu from my front page into the 404 error page in Wordpress - Journo edge-theme.

```
<?php
get_header();
?>



                <div class="edgtf-page-not-found">
                    <?php
                    $edgtf_title_image_404 = journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( '404_page_title_image' );
                    $edgtf_title_404       = journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( '404_title' );
                    $edgtf_subtitle_404    = journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( '404_subtitle' );
                    $edgtf_text_404        = journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( '404_text' );
                    $edgtf_button_label    = journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( '404_back_to_home' );
                    $edgtf_button_style    = journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( '404_button_style' );

                    if ( ! empty( $edgtf_title_image_404 ) ) { ?>
                        <div class="edgtf-404-title-image">
                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $edgtf_title_image_404 ); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr_e( '404 Title Image', 'journo' ); ?>" />
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <h1 class="edgtf-404-title">
                        <?php if ( ! empty( $edgtf_title_404 ) ) {
                            echo esc_html( $edgtf_title_404 );
                        } else {
                            esc_html_e( 'The page you are looking is not found', 'journo' );
                        } ?>
                    </h1>

                    <?php if ( ! empty( $edgtf_subtitle_404 ) ) { ?>
                        <h3 class="edgtf-404-subtitle">
                            <?php echo esc_html( $edgtf_subtitle_404 ); ?>
                        </h3>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <p class="edgtf-404-text">
                        <?php if ( ! empty( $edgtf_text_404 ) ) {
                            echo esc_html( $edgtf_text_404 );
                        } else {
                            esc_html_e( 'The page you are looking for does not exist. It may have been moved, or removed altogether. Perhaps you can return back to the site\'s homepage and see if you can find what you are looking for.', 'journo' );
                        } ?>
                    </p>

                    <?php
                        $button_params = array(
                            'link' => esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
                            'text' => ! empty( $edgtf_button_label ) ? $edgtf_button_label : esc_html__( 'Back to home', 'journo' ),
                            'type' => 'simple'
                        );

                        if ( $edgtf_button_style == 'light-style' ) {
                            $button_params['custom_class'] = 'edgtf-btn-light-style';
                        }

                        echo journo_edge_return_button_html( $button_params );
                    ?>

                    <div class="edgtf-grid edgtf-404-related">
                        <?php echo journo_edge_execute_shortcode('edgtf_layout1', array(
                            'posts_per_page'      => 8,
                            'column_number'       => 4,
                            'space_between_items' => 'normal',
                            'image_size'          => 'custom',
                            'custom_image_width'  => '800',
                            'custom_image_height' => '700',
                            'title_tag'           => 'h4',
                            'display_excerpt'     => 'no',
                            'display_comments'    => 'yes',
                            'display_like'        => 'yes'
                        )); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to look into the top-header at framework/modules/types/top-header/functions.php

But haven't been able to call the function to show the top-menu at the 404 page
Have tried to look in the support of the theme, but nothing and the support of Journo is almost non-existing on this topic.

Hope someone has an answer or an easier solution to the problem.

functions.php code:

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_set_header_top_enabled_class' ) ) {
    function journo_edge_set_header_top_enabled_class( $classes ) {

        if ( journo_edge_is_top_bar_enabled() ) {
            $classes[] = 'edgtf-header-top-enabled';
        }

        return $classes;
    }

    add_filter( 'body_class', 'journo_edge_set_header_top_enabled_class' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_top_header_global_js_var' ) ) {
    function journo_edge_top_header_global_js_var( $global_variables ) {
        $global_variables['edgtfTopBarHeight'] = journo_edge_get_top_bar_height();

        return $global_variables;
    }

    add_filter( 'journo_edge_filter_js_global_variables', 'journo_edge_top_header_global_js_var' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_get_header_top' ) ) {
    /**
     * Loads header top HTML and sets parameters for it
     */
    function journo_edge_get_header_top() {
        $params = array(
            'show_header_top'                => journo_edge_is_top_bar_enabled(),
            'show_header_top_background_div' => journo_edge_get_meta_field_intersect( 'header_type' ) == 'header-box' ? true : false,
            'top_bar_in_grid'                => journo_edge_get_meta_field_intersect( 'top_bar_in_grid' ) == 'yes' ? true : false,
        );

        $params = apply_filters( 'journo_edge_filter_header_top_params', $params );

        journo_edge_get_module_template_part( 'templates/top-header', 'header/types/top-header', '', $params );
    }

    add_action( 'journo_edge_action_before_page_header', 'journo_edge_get_header_top' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_is_top_bar_enabled' ) ) {
    /**
     * Returns is top header area enabled
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    function journo_edge_is_top_bar_enabled() {
        $top_bar_enabled = journo_edge_get_meta_field_intersect( 'top_bar' ) === 'yes' ? true : false;

        if ( is_404() ) {
            $top_bar_enabled = false;
        }

        return apply_filters( 'journo_edge_filter_enabled_top_bar', $top_bar_enabled );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_get_top_bar_height' ) ) {
    /**
     * Returns top header area height
     *
     * @return bool|int|void
     */
    function journo_edge_get_top_bar_height() {
        if ( journo_edge_is_top_bar_enabled() ) {
            $top_bar_height_meta = journo_edge_filter_px( journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'top_bar_height' ) );
            $top_bar_height      = ! empty( $top_bar_height_meta ) ? $top_bar_height_meta : 46;

            return $top_bar_height;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_get_top_bar_background_height' ) ) {
    /**
     * Returns top header area background height
     *
     * @return bool|int|void
     */
    function journo_edge_get_top_bar_background_height() {
        $top_bar_height_meta = journo_edge_filter_px( journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'top_bar_height' ) );
        $header_height_meta  = journo_edge_filter_px( journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'menu_area_height' ) );

        $top_bar_height = ! empty( $top_bar_height_meta ) ? $top_bar_height_meta : 46;
        $header_height  = ! empty( $header_height_meta ) ? $header_height_meta : 90;

        $top_bar_background_height = round( $top_bar_height ) + round( $header_height / 2 );

        return $top_bar_background_height;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_is_top_bar_transparent' ) ) {
    /**
     * Checks if top header area is transparent or not
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    function journo_edge_is_top_bar_transparent() {
        $top_bar_enabled      = journo_edge_is_top_bar_enabled();
        $top_bar_bg_color     = journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'top_bar_background_color' );
        $top_bar_transparency = journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'top_bar_background_transparency' );

        if ( $top_bar_enabled && $top_bar_bg_color !== '' && $top_bar_transparency !== '' ) {
            return $top_bar_transparency >= 0 && $top_bar_transparency < 1;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_is_top_bar_completely_transparent' ) ) {
    /**
     * Checks is top header area completely transparent
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    function journo_edge_is_top_bar_completely_transparent() {
        $top_bar_enabled      = journo_edge_is_top_bar_enabled();
        $top_bar_bg_color     = journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'top_bar_background_color' );
        $top_bar_transparency = journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'top_bar_background_transparency' );

        if ( $top_bar_enabled && $top_bar_bg_color !== '' && $top_bar_transparency !== '' ) {
            return $top_bar_transparency === '0';
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_register_top_header_areas' ) ) {
    /**
     * Registers widget areas for top header bar when it is enabled
     */
    function journo_edge_register_top_header_areas() {
        register_sidebar(
            array(
                'id'            => 'edgtf-top-bar-left',
                'name'          => esc_html__( 'Header Top Bar Left Column', 'journo' ),
                'description'   => esc_html__( 'Widgets added here will appear on the left side in top bar header', 'journo' ),
                'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s edgtf-top-bar-widget">',
                'after_widget'  => '</div>'
            )
        );

        register_sidebar(
            array(
                'id'            => 'edgtf-top-bar-right',
                'name'          => esc_html__( 'Header Top Bar Right Column', 'journo' ),
                'description'   => esc_html__( 'Widgets added here will appear on the right side in top bar header', 'journo' ),
                'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s edgtf-top-bar-widget">',
                'after_widget'  => '</div>'
            )
        );
    }

    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'journo_edge_register_top_header_areas' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_top_bar_grid_class' ) ) {
    /**
     * @param $classes
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function journo_edge_top_bar_grid_class( $classes ) {
        if ( journo_edge_get_meta_field_intersect( 'top_bar_in_grid', journo_edge_get_page_id() ) == 'yes' &&
             journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'top_bar_grid_background_color' ) !== '' &&
             journo_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'top_bar_grid_background_transparency' ) !== '0'
        ) {
            $classes[] = 'edgtf-top-bar-in-grid-padding';
        }

        return $classes;
    }

    add_filter( 'body_class', 'journo_edge_top_bar_grid_class' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'journo_edge_get_top_bar_styles' ) ) {
    /**
     * Sets per page styles for header top bar
     *
     * @param $styles
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function journo_edge_get_top_bar_styles( $styles ) {
        $page_id      = journo_edge_get_page_id();
        $class_prefix = journo_edge_get_unique_page_class( $page_id, true );

        $top_bar_style = array();

        $top_bar_bg_color     = get_post_meta( $page_id, 'edgtf_top_bar_background_color_meta', true );
        $top_bar_border       = get_post_meta( $page_id, 'edgtf_top_bar_border_meta', true );
        $top_bar_border_color = get_post_meta( $page_id, 'edgtf_top_bar_border_color_meta', true );

        $current_style = '';

        $top_bar_selector = array(
            $class_prefix . ' .edgtf-top-bar'
        );

        if ( $top_bar_bg_color !== '' ) {
            $top_bar_transparency = get_post_meta( $page_id, 'edgtf_top_bar_background_transparency_meta', true );
            if ( $top_bar_transparency === '' ) {
                $top_bar_transparency = 1;
            }
            $top_bar_style['background-color'] = journo_edge_rgba_color( $top_bar_bg_color, $top_bar_transparency );
        }

        if ( $top_bar_border == 'yes' ) {
            $top_bar_style['border-bottom'] = '1px solid ' . $top_bar_border_color;
        } elseif ( $top_bar_border == 'no' ) {
            $top_bar_style['border-bottom'] = '0';
        }

        $current_style .= journo_edge_dynamic_css( $top_bar_selector, $top_bar_style );

        $current_style = $current_style . $styles;

        return $current_style;
    }

    add_filter( 'journo_edge_filter_add_page_custom_style', 'journo_edge_get_top_bar_styles' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check your htaccess file and try to change permalinks.
if you are not done with this so use mega menu WordPress plugin its same as per your theme.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/